# Extend lifetime of an object by taking a reference out of option

Tags: rust

I'd like to define a struct representing a node in a graph, but in a way that it is possible to drop the reference later on. It would be easy with Box or Rc but I would prefer not to heap allocate this.

I believe that the problem can be abstracted to sth like that:

```
struct B<'a> {  
    b: Option<&'a B<'a>>,                                                  
}                                                                               
                                                                        
fn f() {                                                                 
    let mut b: B;
    {
        let a = B { b: None };
        b = B { b: Some(&a) };
        b.b.take();
    }
    b;
}
```

So this is perfectly fine for the var b to live in the outside block but compiler seems to be too restrictive here.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: It's restrictive because you create a local object `a`, then you store a reference on it in `b` (you don't change ownership), then you use `b` when `a` is already gone, so `b` would contain a dangling pointer if it would compile. Why would Rust allow you that?

Comment: The option being `None` doesn't unbind it from `a`'s lifetime. Lifetimes are baked into the type.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov When I do `b.b.take()` I remove the pointer to `a` so there is no dangling pointer.

Comment: @kmdreko yes, this is the core of the problem. The q is how to workaround this.

Comment: You can't have `B` have a lifetime and also write code like this, so there isn't really a good answer other than "don't do this". Does your actual code strictly need a lifetime? Can `B` own the child `B` instance instead?

Comment: This is question contains [Misconception #8 from Common Rust Lifetime Misconceptions](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#8-lifetimes-can-grow-and-shrink-at-run-time). TLDR: lifetimes are statically-verified at compile-time, they cannot dynamically grow or shrink at run-time.

Comment: If you're trying to create a graph structure with references, you're going to have a bad time. *"I would prefer not to heap allocate this"* - I'm not sure how you're building a graph without dynamic allocations, but the more standard ways would be with `Rc`s or indexes/ids backed by a collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the compiler being restrictive,
when you declare

```
struct B<'a> {  
    b: Option<&'a B<'a>>,                                                  
}
```

you are telling the compiler that B.b is going to live as long as B
and what you want to do is tell  the compiler that b has a lifetime of b and B as a lifetime of a.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    b: i32,
}

struct Wrap<'a, 'b>{
    a: Option<&'a Foo>,
    b: Option<&'b Foo>,

}


fn main() {
    let mut w =  Wrap {
        a: None, 
        b: None,
    };
    w.b = Some(&Foo{b:0});
    {

        w.a = Some(&Foo{b: 1});
        w.a.take();

    }
    println!("b = {:?}", w.b);
}
```

I don't know if this code will help but TLDR you have to specify a second lifetime.